# Pandas DataFrame: Subtract columns with string datatype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I subtract two columns that contain values of type string? No values are indicated by '---' and should lead to a '---' in the result. The result should also be of value type string.

**Source**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'y': ['5', '---', '7']})

    x   y
0   'a' '5'
1   'b' '---'
2   'c' '7'

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'y': ['1', '2', '---']})

    x    y
0   'a'  '1'
1   'b'  '2'
2   'c'  '---'
```

**Target**

```
df3 = df1 - df2

    x   y
0   'a' '4'
1   'b' '---'
2   'c' '---'
```

Comment: Use `pd.to_numeric(..., errors='coerce')` to make then numbers, then subtract the specific columns and convert back to strings using `fillna('--').astype(str)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
df1.set_index('x').apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x,errors='coerce')).sub(
      df2.set_index('x').apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x,errors='coerce'))).fillna('--')\
                                                                .reset_index()
```

---

```
   x   y
0  a   4
1  b  --
2  c  --
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `pd.to_numeric` to both replace all `'---'` to `NaNs`, and also also cast all values to `floats`:

```
df1['y'] = pd.to_numeric(df1['y'], errors='coerce')
df2['y'] = pd.to_numeric(df2['y'], errors='coerce')
```

The simply subtract both columns and store the result in `df1` for instance:

```
df1['y'] = (df1['y'] - df2['y']).replace(np.nan,'---')

   x    y
0  a    4
1  b  ---
2  c  ---
```